# Data not posting in MySQL table from PHP. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here

Tags: php, mysql

I think I have done everything right. It must be a silly mistake. I have set up the MySQL connection and used real string escape for security.Please point out my error or suggest me if it can be done in other way?

Also please suggest me a way on how to retrieve the submitted data in my database and get that data to another xml file or email.

```
<?php 
//is there a problem in connection? 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
if($link == false){
die("error"); }
if(
isset($_POST['name']) &&
isset($_POST['type']) &&
isset($_POST['email']) &&
isset($_POST['website']) &&
isset($_POST['app']) &&
isset($_POST['phone']) &&
isset($_POST['about']))
{
//real escape string is used, is it affecting my data? 
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['type']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
$website = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['website']);
$app = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['app']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['phone']);
$about = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['about']);

//query has been created 
$query = "INSERT INTO `contact_form` (name, type, email, website, app,
phone, about) VALUES ('$name', '$type', '$email', '$website', '$app', '$phone', '$about')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $query)){
    echo 'the form has been submitted successfully';
}else{
    echo 'there was some problem';
}

}   
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<h3>Post your startup info</h3>
<ul>
<li><label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span></label><input type="text" name="name" placeholder=" startup/business name"></li>
<li><label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span></label><input type="text" name="type" placeholder=" startup/business type"></li>
<li><label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></label><input type="text" name="email" placeholder=" email address"></li>
<li><label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span></label><input type="text" name="website" placeholder=" website link"></li>
<li><label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span></label><input type="text" name="app" placeholder=" app link"></li>
<li><label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></label><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder=" phone number"></li>
<li><label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></label><textarea name="about" rows="6" placeholder="write about your startup/business in short"></textarea></li>
<li class="startup_submit"><button type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button></li>
</ul>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Forget to select database. Pass fourth parameter as your database read http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: i don't think the db_name which is the last parameter in mysqli_connect is optional.

Comment: Don't bother with all this real_escape stuff. See prepared statements instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `mysqli_select_db` for select database in which you are going to add records.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// ...some PHP code for database "my_db"...

// Change database to "test"
mysqli_select_db($con,"test");

// ...some PHP code for database "test"...

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```